# Use google calendar UI in my android app

Tags: android, user-interface, calendar, google-calendar-api

Hey sorry if this is a very simple question, I'm getting back in to app development and frankly I don't remember much of anything.

**Is there a way to get the Google calendar UI in an app I am making?** It doesn't have to actually use Google calendar data or API, that's not the functionality I'm looking for. But I am open to using the entire Google Calendar system if it lets me use the UI.

If it matters, the app I am making is just a simple scheduler. I'm not great with UI design and for now I would like to just use the google Calendar frontend while I work on the backend.

(I really hope I am using all these words right haha)

Thanks for the help.

Update: I posted an update in the Comments, I don't know if thats the common practice or not.

Comment: What have you tried? Please establish an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do some research, try your hand at it, and show us what you did and what went wrong or where you got stuck.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Perhaps some mockups that illustrate the flow of your app.

Comment: please check [this](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) calendar widget library from Square

Comment: So what is the normal practice, updating a post or commenting?
Anyway I'm working on a MCVE I guess, I'll show something once I've made enough progress to not be embarrassed by it haha.

As for clarifying what I want to do: I want to make an app that add's and edits events based on certain settings. I've got how all that works down. I figured though since lot's of people use google Calendar it would be good to make it just edit and update their existing calendar.

Currently I am figuring out how to get Calendars and Calendar events with permissions, not as a sync adapter.